# black screen when I run my iOS application

Tags: ios

I'm trying to do a new iOS app in Xcode. I made a main storyboard and I added a label on my ViewController. When I run my application, first second it show the label and then become the screen black without any errors.

I'm working on Xcode 11 (Swift 5) and this message appears on output:

> [SceneConfiguration] Info.plist configuration "Default Configuration" for UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication contained UISceneDelegateClassName key, but could not load class with name "gina.SceneDelegate"

I don't know where my mistake is.

[image: black screen when running]

Comment: please post [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I think you remove your SceneDelegate class from your project

Comment: A lot of the answers below seem to miss the point of the error and describe fixes that aren't relevant to the exact error in question. In my case, I'd just forgotten to add the `SceneDelegate` to my target and checking the box fixed it.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

### iOS 13 & above

> Only if target is 13 or greater.

`SceneDelegate` is not supported before **iOS 13**. If you want to use `SceneDelegate` and also want to support **iOS prior to iOS 13** then you a have to add some changes to your project.

1. Add availability attribute to the whole class in *SceneDelegate.swift* file.

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {
   ...
}
```

2. *AppDelegate.swift* file has two new `SceneDelegate` method. Add availability attribute to them as well.

```swift
@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, configurationForConnecting connectingSceneSession: UISceneSession, options: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) -> UISceneConfiguration {
  ...
}

@available(iOS 13.0, *)
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didDiscardSceneSessions sceneSessions: Set<UISceneSession>) {
  ...
}
```

3. Lastly, add `UIWindow` object in *AppDelegate.swift*.

```swift
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    //Add this line
    var window: UIWindow?

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

    ...
}
```

---

### iOS 12 and earlier

`AppDelegate` needs a `UIWindow` property. **iOS 13** uses `SceneDelegate` in new projects. Specify the `UIWindow` object and remove the *SceneDelegate.swift* file.

If you have removed the `SceneDelegate` from project, then you must remove the ***Application Scene Manifest*** dictionary from **Info.plist**.

[image: Info.plist]

Comment: Great, Thank you

Answer (score 5):

You need to initialize the window like this:

```
let window = UIWindow(windowScene: scene as! UIWindowScene)
```

and add these in info.plist:

```
<key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <true/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
                    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

That's all you need to do.

Comment: I had same issue, prefixing `$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).` resolved my issue.